# PHP get array values and use it inside of other array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$post[] = intval($row[counted]);
$descrip = $row[desc];
}
```

and use $post in this:

```
$pie->set_values( array($post,new pie_value($post[1], ".$descrip.")) );
```

but i get this result:

```
values": [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], { "value": 1, "label": ".PROCESADOR INTEL CELERON G530." } ] } ]
```

The problem is that the result need to be like this:

```
values": [  1, 1, 1, 1 , { "value": 1, "label": ".PROCESADOR INTEL CELERON G530." } ] } ]
```

I have to remove the [ ] of the post array. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add the object of class **pie_value** as the last element of the array to pass?

```
$post[] = new pie_value($post[1], ".$descrip.");
$pie->set_values( $post );
```

Answer (score 0):

You add as first parameter an array, so you got an array as first parameter.

You could simplify this like this: (not tested)

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($post as $p)
    $arr[] = $p;

// Add the other parameters
$arr[] = new pie_value($post[1], ".$descrip.");

$pie->set_values( $arr );
```

Comment: im getting the same result: [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] i need just the numbers not the [ ] cause when i use it in other array i get an error

Comment: I don't understand. You said, that you want to remove the []. If you iterate through the $post array, and add each element on its own, then you get want you want.